# the authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server osu api

Tags: python, api, flask, python-requests

context [osu api documentation](https://osu.ppy.sh/docs/index.html?javascript#authorization-code-grant)

the user will press a login button which will direct them to an authorization website [osu auth](https://osu.ppy.sh/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=5679&redirect_uri=https://osu-api-crap.minecreeper0913.repl.co/code_grab&scope=public)

then will be redirected back to the website with a code

```
  code = request.query_string

  name_verify = str(code).split('code=')[1]
  #re.search("(?!\w+=)\w+", str(code)) #getting the code
  print(name_verify)

  response = requests.post("https://osu.ppy.sh/oauth/token", data = { 'client_id': xxxx, 'client_secret': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 'redirect_uri': "https://osu-api-crap.minecreeper0913.repl.co", 'scope':'public', 'code': name_verify, 'grant_type':'authorization_code'}, headers={'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

  print(response.text)
```

I have been told that this is the correct way to do it but it always results in "the authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server"

Comment: Can you try with "json =" instead of "body=" in the post method?

Comment: alright I tried that and it gave me {"error":"client authentication failed"} so it did something, do you think you could explain to me why json= is better than data=/body=?

Comment: "json=" sends a json serializable python object while "data =" sends a string instance containing json doc. You should use data while sending  form data content type while json for other content types.

Comment: oh ok I get it. also do you think you know why that error is appearing or a fix?

Comment: It looks like one of the body parameter you are sending is wrong. I would suggest go through the osu docs first and check when this error is thrown

Comment: ahh ok I will check that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Content-Type of **Token Request** (RFC 6749 [Section 4.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3)) must be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` although the format of **Token Response** (RFC 6749 [Section 4.1.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.4)) is JSON.

Comment: when I use that it goes back to the authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server.